# CSS transition property can't be used twice for a selector?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

### CSS `transition` property not functioning as expected

I am trying to add different transitions for the different properties, but the `transition` seems to not be working, as I expected.

---

Here is my **CSS** code

```
* {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 80ms linear;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
  }
```

I am probably doing something really obvious wrong, but if you can help, I do appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention, but only the last transition is executed. The browser seems to ignore the previous ones and overrides them with the last one

Comment: Will help you out with a quick hint. CSS uses the last declaration of a property that's why it is called CASCADING style sheet! @Santi is correct just comma separate them.

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov check my answer. Is that what you wished for ?

Comment: @YashYadav You do notice you posted an identical answer to mine minutes after I had already posted? OP gets a notification when you post an answer - no need to comment and let them know.

Comment: @Santi ummm ? I dont' see who is posting and who is not. I was just writing code so it took me some time. Sorry if I hurt your feelings .

Comment: My feelings aren't hurt. Seeing as you seem to be new-ish to posting on Stack Overflow (judging by rep score), I was merely pointing out that posting an answer *and* a comment telling OP to look at your answer is poor etiquette. I understand that duplicates happen, however asking OP to consider yours over the other is essentially groveling. You can choose to take the advice, or think I'm attacking you personally. Good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the same CSS property multiple times will result in previous declarations being overwritten, and only the last being kept. (Assuming they have identical [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)).

You can comma-separate transitions like so:

```
transition: all .5s ease-in-out, opacity 80ms linear, background .2s ease-out;
```

---

**Demonstration:**

```css
* {
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out, opacity 2s linear, background 4s ease-out;
}

div {
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

div:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>hover this</div>
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks! I was sure I am doing something really stupid =D